# Getting data from database in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, resultset

Ok, I have a table with only one column and one field (it's suppose to be a password)
from Oracle, and I want to get this String and save it in a local variable in order
to compare it later on with another variable.

So, the important part of my code looks like this:

```
try {

   conn = IAPMain.Link(conn);
   st = conn.createStatement();
   rsPass = st.executeQuery("select pass from password");

   while(rsPass.next()) {

       pass = rsPass.getString("pass");

   }


   }catch(SQLException e) {

       System.err.println(e);

   }
```

But the program won't get through the while loop.
So, the error here is that the result is supposed to be saved on the variable "pass".

I have tried several ways but nothing has worked so far, so, yeah, I'm kind of
desperate at this point.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does your query return anything if you run it with your SQL client directly?

Comment: Also post the error you are getting.

Comment: I'm sorry, a_horse_with_no_name, I'm not pretty sure what do you mean.

Comment: May be your table does not contain data. Or you didn't commit data inserted in other transaction. So it looks empty in other session.

Answer (score 0):

if the column and table name are really lowercase then try

```
 rsPass = st.executeQuery("select \"pass\" from \"password\"");
```

otherwise select using uppercase